# vtiger : create new module or add blocks to account module

Tags: php, crm, vtiger

Please have a look on to the specification given below. I have a doubt that whether I need to create a new module named "callout" or add blocks to existing module account.  The reason for the doubt is the line "The following new blocks should be associated with the Accounts Module" in specification . What is it mean ?. Do i need to create a callout module and make the account module as a related module or add all the given blocks to the existing account module ?.

Callout Add-on Module

Introduction

The purpose of the Callout Add-on Module is to provide an interface where callout incidents can be tracked through their entire lifecycle, from callout incident creation through to invoice. The reason for the doubt is the line "The following new blocks should be associated with the Accounts Module;" in the given specification. What is mean by that ?. do i need to create a callout module and make the account module as related module ? or add all the given blocks in account module itself. Please help its very urgent

Table Schema

The following new blocks should be associated with the Accounts Module;

New block title: Response Service Providers
RSP Name – drop-down – taken from vTiger Vendors
RSP Phone - Lookup

Notes: Require the ability to create multiple Response Service Providers

New block title: General Keyholding Information
Key Location – drop down – taken from vTiger Vendors
Nearest Tube, Parking – text 50 chars
External patrol –

New block title: Premises Entry
Instructions – text 500 chars (include the following notation; including doors to open, lights, light switch location, cautions and gotchas)
Fire Exits

New block title: Alarm Details
Keypad Location – text 50 chars
Alarm Code – text 50 chars
Un-setting Procedure – text 50 chars
Password – text 50 chars
Reset Procedure – text 50 chars
Alarm Response Company – dropdown – taken from vTiger Vendors
Service Telephone Number – text 50 chars
Alarm Company Reference – text 50 chars
ARC Telephone Numbers – text 50 chars
ARC Reference – text 50 chars
Alarm Reset – text 50 chars
Zone Chart – text 50 chars
Main Alarm Control Location – text 50 chars

New block title: Health and Safety
Interior Risks - text 50 chars
Exterior Risks - text 50 chars
Other risks – text 50 chars

New block title: Utilities
Cleaning Company – text 50 chars
Cleaning Company Hours – text 50 chars
Location of gas – text 50 chars
Location of water – text 50 chars
Location of electricity – text 50 chars
Authorisation for temporary repairs – text 50 chars

New block title: Fire Alarm
Fire alarm instructions – text 50 chars

New Callout Add-on Module – Phase 1

Written in PHP & MySQL

Initial logon screen to include: company code, username and password.  Username and passwords are those created and maintained in vTiger.
Notes: Company code logon required to differentiate client vTiger databases, i.e. CKH London, CKH Manchester, CKH Bristol etc.
5 logon attempts only and then lockout for 30 mins

On successful logon, secondary screen is Control Desk summary view of active callouts.  Only show one line per callout record with the following column titles;
CKH No
Account Name
Response Service Provider Name
Response Service Phone
Status
Include ability to sort active callouts by all column titles by clicking on column title
Note: May want colour coding of active callouts – tbd

Include New Callout button
Provide a search box where any detail of the vTiger account can be entered, i.e. CKH No, address, postcode etc.  Once located, then provide the ability to enter the following information;
Alarm Activation Received - date & time
ARC Name - lookup
ARC Operators Reference
Job Accepted – date & time
Job Accepted By – text 50 chars
RSP Name – dropdown
RSP Accepted – date and time
RSP Accepted By – text 50 chars
RSP Acceptance Ref – text 50 chars
Keyguard Name – text 50 chars
Keyguard Mobile Number – text 50 chars
All information above to be provided by the Controller

When the new callout is saved, a unique callout ref is generated and also a callout password.

Include Text To… button to text the information to the Keyguard (specific text information to be provided)

Include ability to edit active callouts by clicking on any item of one line callout summary.  Edit screen to include the following additional information;
Callout Ref
Callout Password

New Android application: Keyguard logon screen (using Callout Ref and password obtained verbally from Controller or from text message).

Alarm Activation Received - date & time
ARC Name - lookup
ARC Operators Reference
Job Accepted – date & time
Job Accepted By – text 50 chars
RSP Name – dropdown
RSP Accepted – date and time
RSP Accepted By – text 50 chars
RSP Acceptance Ref – text 50 chars
Keyguard Name – text 50 chars (can be edited by the Keyguard)
Keyguard Mobile Number – text 50 chars (can be edited by the Keyguard)
All information above to be available to the Keyguard but read-only

Additional information that can be edited by the Keyguard;
Time on Site – date & time
Alarm System Display – text 50 chars
Cause of Activation – text 250 chars
Persons on Site – text 50 chars
Persons Called to Site – text 50 chars
Method of Alarm Reset – text 50 chars
Time of Alarm Reset – date & time
Notes – text 250 chars
Time Leaving Site – date & time
Controller confirmation of alarm armed – date & time

New Callout Add-on Module – Phase 2
Overview
Once the Keyguard has left the site and the controller has confirmed that the alarm has been armed the Controller changes the callout status to “Ready for Validation”.  This triggers the Callout Validation process.  A member of CKH must validate the callout incident.  An automated e-Mail then goes to the Account Contact with the details of the callout and an Invoice is generated.

Answer (score 2):

To add the block or add the fields in exiting module

$Vtiger_Utils_Log = true;

include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Menu.php');

include_once('vtlib/Vtiger/Module.php');

$module = new Vtiger_Module();

$module->name = 'Accounts';

$module = $module->getInstance('Accounts');

// Add the basic module block

$block1 = new Vtiger_Block();

$block1->label = 'LBL_ACCOUNT_INFORMATION';

$block1 = $block1->getInstance($block1->label,$module);

$field3 = new Vtiger_Field();

$field3->name = 'orgtype';

$field3->table = $module->basetable;

$field3->label = 'Account Type';

$field3->column = 'orgtype';

$field3->columntype = 'VARCHAR(255)';

$field3->uitype = 2;

$field3->typeofdata = 'V~M';

$block1->addField($field3);